# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_rest_auth'

Tags: python, django, conda, pipenv, pipenv-install

I don't get why I am getting this problem I followed most the steps to the guide in installing: https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
Except that I used `pipenv install`.
However, `python manage.py migrate` gave me this error:

```
    main()
  File "/home/ryan/Documents/is4103/is4103-capstone-id01/Backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ryan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 223, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_rest_auth'
```

settings.py

```
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'BackendApp',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dj_rest_auth',
]
```

Pipfile

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
requests = "*"
django = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
django-polymorphic = "*"
pillow = "*"
djangorestframework = "*"
markdown = "*"
django-filter = "*"
dj-rest-auth = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

Edit: this repo is on github so I reclone it and tried, but same error.

Comment: Check your pipfile.lock.do you find dj_rest in the file?

Comment: Yes dj_rest_auth is in that file

Comment: You installed it in the virtualenv. try installing it globally also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I am wrong about this, it is because I am not in `pipenv shell` environement when I am installing `dj_auth_rest`

Old Wrong answer:

My Anaconda is causing this issue somehow.

i used `conda deactivate` to resolve this.